# Motor Constants Understanding

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I have a basic question regarding the constants of a motor. I want to know the name of the constants and their SI unit.

Torque (T) = Kt x Flux x Ia

Back EMF (E) = Ke x Flux x speed

When flux is constant,

Kt x flux = Ki

Ke x flux = Kb

I want to know the following defined names are correct or not.

Kt - motor torque constant, motor armature constant (N. m/A)

Ke - feedback constant, motor voltage constant, electic constant, back emf constant, counter emf equation constant (V. s/rad or V/rads-1)

Ki - what is the name of it and SI unit?

Kb - what is the name of it and SI unit?

And what is motor gain constant and motor constant?

Comment: Did you check the SI yourself? What is the unit of flux? Check whether Kt in [Nm/A] matches with: *Torque (T) = Kt x Flux x Ia*

Comment: If Kb = Ke x flux then kb must (according to your formulas above) equal E/speed. Does that give you some room to derive your own answers?

Comment: The conventional Kt and Kv you'll see in most motor datasheets already incorporate your flux term, so that Torque = Kt * I, Speed = Kv * V.